# Discord music bot NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code :

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print("Song done!"))
voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
voice.source.volume = 0.07
```

I got this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Answer (score 0):

It means the voice is None...

Did you try connecting to the channel?
Are you executing the command in the same guild as that channel?

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_channels
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_client